# Apache fediz 1.2 - Context initialization failed

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, plugins

I am trying to set up the fedizhelloworld example on two apache-tomcat-7.0.59 servers (one for the RP and one for the IDP)

I am having trouble with the IDP and am getting the following errors on startup.

catalina.out:

```
 2015-05-21 13:58:06,176 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR
 org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader  - Context
 initialization failed <openjpa-2.3.0-r422266:1540826 nonfatal general
 error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException: There were
 errors initializing your configuration: <openjpa-2.3.0-r422266:1540826
 fatal user error> org.apache.openjpa.util.UserException: A connection
 could not be obtained for driver class "null" and URL "null".  You may
 have specified an invalid URL.
```

idp.log:

```
 2015-05-21 13:42:45,456 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR
 org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader  - Context
 initialization failed <openjpa-2.3.0-r422266:1540826 nonfatal general
 error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException: There were
 errors initializing your configuration: <openjpa-2.3.0-r422266:1540826
 fatal user error> org.apache.openjpa.util.UserException: A connection
 could not be obtained for driver class "null" and URL "null".  You may
 have specified an invalid URL.
```

This is my server.xml settup:

```
<Server port="9005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">

<!-- http configuration -->
   <Connector port="9080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
        connectionTimeout="20000"
        redirectPort="9443" />

<!-- https configuration -->
   <Connector port="9443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
        maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
        keystoreFile="idp-ssl-server.jks"
        keystorePass="tompass" sslProtocol="TLS" />
```

I made the start up/shutdown scripts in CATALINA_HOME:

```
#!/bin/bash

CATALINA_HOME=/home/mmcginn/Sites/fireworks/SAML_lab/CXF_Lab/tomcat-7-IDP
$CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh
```

and...

```
#!/bin/bash

CATALINA_HOME=/home/mmcginn/Sites/fireworks/SAML_lab/CXF_Lab/tomcat-7-IDP
$CATALINA_HOME/bin/shutdown.sh
```

I put the example keystore in CATALINA_HOME "idp-ssl-sever.jks"
Then finally, I deployed "fediz-idp.war" and "fediz-idp-sts.war" to the webapps folder.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading and adding a hsqldb driver (jar) into to your fediz idp lib directory ($CATALINA_HOME/webapps/fediz-idp/WEB-INF/lib). You may check your persitence.properties, persistenceContext.xml config.